# Can someone help me make this circuit work?

Tags: bjt, oscillator, ltspice, resonance, tank

I am trying to implement the circuit described in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8846110) in LTspice. The circuit is shown below:

[image]

The paper claims that the circuit can be used to measure the resonant frequency of the coupled LC tank. By changing the voltage of the varactor diode, the frequency of oscillation of the Colpitt's oscillator is changed to generate a frequency sweep. At the resonant frequency, the emitter current (or voltage Ve) is maximum. However, on simulating the circuit, I get the same value of Ve. The waveform of Ve is as shown below:
[image]

It does not change with the varactor diode capacitance, even though I have designed the circuit such that resonance should have occured when the varactor diode voltage will be 5V.

Edit: I am including the output of the oscillator as well:

[image]

Comment: What value of M did you use for mutual coupling? And did fo change when C7 was removed which will define fo if M is too high. I suspect gain must be changed from 20/10 to AC coupled 20k/100

Comment: R8, R9 so low ? OPamp is perhaps functional. k L1 L3 0 ?

Comment: `k L1 L3 0` - the `0` means "zero mutual coupling." Normally this is 1 for "ideal mutual coupling."

Comment: The opamp doesn't make any difference. It just provides gain because I wanted the output to be in Volts. Even before the opamp Ve gives the same shape. As for the value of k, the 0 is just for something I was trying out... I have tried with several values of k, it doesn't make much difference. Ideally k is around 0.01 according to the paper I am referring.

Comment: If you expect a voltage that is representative of "current consumed" by oscillator, signal would be "rectified and filtered" because of the presence of oscillations.

Comment: If you want to oscillate an LC-tank at it's resonant frequency, I'd suggest trying this circuit based on a LM311 comparator: http://web.archive.org/web/20040902205305/http://www.amqrp.org/kits/elsie/ELSIE_BA.PDF You can ignore the microcontroller. Just connect your tank where L1/C1 are located and hook up a frequency counter to the output of the LM311 (pin 7). It works for a large range of L and C values and is the basis for a lot of LC-meter designs, e.g. do google search for "LM311 LC meter". And with a LM339 -- http://www.kerrywong.com/2010/10/16/avr-lc-meter-with-frequency-measurement/

Comment: Besides what the others have said, `C4` is completely useless across `V1` if `Rser=0`. But if you can include `C4` in the source as `Cpar=<...>` (obviously with `Rser>0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try replacing V1 by a step pulse (ok, included in LTSpice as parameter). Some time, it helps. Oscillation must be seen.

Ok. Simulations done for understanding the basic schematic.I only change R1 and R2 (polarization).
All made with microcap 12 from http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm

Basically, it is a "grid dip meter" for the "old radioamators"  :) .

The essential variable is then K1 (coupling to the tag ... or another L with Cparasitic circuit tank, if you want to know what is its self-resonnant frequency). And the "knob" is C5. Here restricted in a "certain band" of frequencies.

Let's go. Sorry for the numerous pictures. Is it possible to "send" files ?

The pictures are tran or ac=sin analysis (see low noted T(Secs) or F(Hz)). The parameter (if one) is noted in the high of the picture. The value noted -> line in grey color (in principle, if I made it :)  ). DC Supply (5V) is in serial with sin generator (1V, would be 1mV, relative) (for ac and tran analysis), some interference seen in tran analysis ... Note that magnitude output is important (some 15 v peak, no "load"). C5 is the simulated varactor. Good luck for the next step ...

Some other things. VE may need a "compagnon" voltage (With 2 resistors). Differential measuring and a "stable power supply" with good decoupling capacitor.

After reviewing and simulating, unfortunaly or happyly ... I made an error in the schematic ! Do you see it ?

[image: General tran analysis]
[image: General tran analysis, same expanded end]
[image: Ve(t,K1)]
[image: Ve(t,C5)]
[image: Vout(F,C5)]
[image: Vout(F,K1)]
[image: Vout(F,C4)]

For more information, look for the operation of the coupled circuits, primary and secondary tuned. Here is a simulation when the coupling k changes ... k=0.01 is line in red.

[image]

Comment: It is not the oscillations that I am having trouble with as you can see. I am unable to obtain desired waveform of Vout

Comment: Ok. I see the abstract. It seems to be, as old function, a "grid-dip meter" with a varicap for finding the frequency without turning a knob. I will search if some schematic exist too.

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/document/164208883/Grid-Dip-Meter. Other can be usefull.  C4a and C4B can be varactors.

Comment: I just finished trying something. Will add answer tomorrow :) Not too convincing ... but a good start. I need the rfid frequency.

Comment: Yes it's like a grid dip meter. Thanks a lot for your time and help! I look forward to yout answer!

Comment: With great pleasure.

Comment: Wow thank you soo much for investing so much time and effort for helping out a random stranger! Bless you! A couple of questions regarding the simulations though, k should be fixed if I don't vary the distance between the coils. Also what are the last three plots of? I am not able to understand what they show. Thanks once again for your help! I will keep your points in mind and try to make my simulation work.

Comment: The last three graphs show how the operating frequency of your edit will change as you change the value of the parameter.
Example: curves relating to the parameter K (before last). The gray-white curve (on the left) is that corresponding to k = 0.2 (see top of the figure). The tip of the curves goes up a little while going to the right where is the last one for k = 0 (curve in brown just next to the curve in very dark blue.

Comment: This means that if k varies, the found operating frequency will shift a little lower. The curve that interests you is that of the tran simulation with parameter K, but also the fourth (parameter C5), because the assembly uses a varactor ... because it is necessary to be able to fix the frequency of the reading. C1 is worth 56 pF ... The assembly is no longer a "Colpitts" :)

Comment: Love eachother. Do you remember who said it?

Comment: For more information, look for the operation of the coupled circuits, primary and secondary tuned.

Comment: Thank you! Your inputs helped me in building a circuit similar to this with some changes and there is a discernable change in voltage at resonance so I can detect it!